# How can I read Cassandra data using JDBC from pySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

In order to parallelize the read operation and read with more than one executor. Rather than the following read code, I want to read with JDBC.

```
hosts ={"spark.cassandra.connection.host":'node1_ip,node2_ip,node3_ip',
   "table":"ex_table","keyspace":"ex_keyspace"}
data_frame=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .options(**hosts).load()
```

How can I read Cassandra data using JDBC from pySpark?

Comment: using JDBC with Cassandra will be very inefficient... What is the problem with Spark Cassandra Connector?

Comment: @AlexOtt i can not use parallel reading .Only 1 executor work when i use Cassandra Connector. I tried repartition but it did not solve my problem still only one executor work when i try to read from cassandra . I want to improve reading speed with running on multiple executors.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to ensure multiple core work ?

Comment: it looks like you have a huge partition... If yes, JDBC won't help much here as well

Comment: Yes i have huge partition . Do you have any suggestion for my stand alone  clustured system to use multiple core (rather than only one)?

Comment: Not much possible - as I remember reading of the single partition is always done by one core

Answer (score 0):

DataStax provides a JDBC driver for Apache Spark which allows you to connect to Cassandra from Spark using a JDBC connection.

The JDBC driver is available to download from the [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers) site.

See the instructions for [Installing the Simba JDBC driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/doc/install-simba-jdbc-driver.html). Additionally, there is also a [User Guide](https://downloads.datastax.com/jdbc/2.6.7.1008/Simba%20Spark%20JDBC%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf) for configuring the driver with some examples. Cheers!